# Powershell single quote all array elements in parameters before SQL EXEC

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I have the below code snippet and all is working fine except that it looks like none of the values are wrapped in single quotes which the stored procedure gives out about.

Is there a way to tell it to wrap each element in `$p` in single quotes before the SQL is executed?

`$p` contains 30 different elements which can be numeric or alpha-numeric.

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][array]$p
)
Process {
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=OurServer;Initial Catalog=OurDatabase;Integrated Security=true"

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $cmd.Connection = $conn
    $cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    $cmd.CommandText = "EXEC sp_test $p"
}
```

Comment: Please consider using `$cmd.Parameters` instead and `$cmd.CommandType = "StoredProcedure"`, avoiding both quoting issues and possible SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options to update array elements:

```
# Using -replace
$p = $p -replace '^.*$','''$&'''

# Using foreach-object and string format operator
$p = $p | Foreach-Object { "'{0}'" -f $_ }

# Using foreach method
$p = $p.foreach({"'$_'"})
```

Comment: Only problem here is if the value is empty is only adds a single quote like `'` when you would expect `''` for the first option.